# IOS In App Purchase never leaves active state

Tags: debugging, ios7, in-app-purchase, swift

I have an in app purchase with hosted content in swift. No errors. My download queue is as follows:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedDownloads downloads:[AnyObject]){
    for download:AnyObject in downloads {
        if let down:SKDownload = download as? SKDownload  {
            switch down.downloadState {
            case .Active:
                NSLog("Active %@ %@",down.progress,down.timeRemaining)
                break
            case .Cancelled:
                NSLog("%@","download cancelled")
                break
            case .Failed:
                NSLog("%@","download failed")
                productTitle.text = "Download Failed"
                break
            case .Finished:
                NSLog("%@","download finished")
                var source = down.contentURL.relativePath
                var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
                var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:source.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path))

                if !dict.objectForKey("Files"){
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(down.transaction)
                    return
                }



                if let arr = dict["Files"] as? [String] {
                    for file in arr {
                        let content:String = source.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Contents").stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
                        self.copyPathToDocsFolder(source,target:content)
                    }
                }

                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(down.transaction)
                NSLog("Download Complete");
                productTitle.text = "Download Complete";

            case .Paused:
                    NSLog("%@","SKDownloadStatePaused")
                    break
            case .Waiting:
                    NSLog("%@","SKDownloadStateWaiting")
                    break
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my copy method that never gets called.

```
func copyPathToDocsFolder(source:String,target:String) {
    NSLog("Copy function called")
    let filemgr:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let docsDir = dirPaths;

    let targetPath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(target)

    var error:NSError?


    if (filemgr.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath:target, error:&error)) {
        NSLog("Great Success");
    }
    else {
        NSLog("Error copying file:");
    }
}
```

I'm working on a real, licensed and provisioned device. When the download delegate begins, Active traces out in the first case of the delegate's switch statement, but the download progress and the time remaining are both nil. Any ideas? I don't really know how to debug this as there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case .Finished statement

```
var source = down.contentURL.relativePath
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:source.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path))
```

Should be

```
var source = down.contentURL.relativePath                    
var dict =   NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: source.stringByAppendingPathComponent("ContentInfo.plist"))
```

NSBundle.mainBundle(). has no business being there.